# Can I work as a postdoc with EAD as a J-2 visa holder?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, visa

My wife started to work with a J-1 visa in the US as a postdoc. I am also a scientist, but i am here as a spouse with J-2 visa. I would like to know, if is it possible to work as a postdoc with employment authorization document (EAD).

Comment: I would think so, but you really need an official ruling. Ask the immigration authorities or the HR office at a research university. I don't see how a post-doc is different from any other work for pay for immigration purposes, though.